# Sending categorical data as feature for SBERT

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, bert-language-model

I'm very new to NLP and I'm trying to pre-train the SBERT model for finding semantic similarity between job titles. I understand that we can fine-tune it using tripletLoss Function by passing similar/Non-similar examples but if i have categories for those examples, How can i pass them along ?

For example :
[image: Examples of training set]

In the above example, you can see the top two rows belong to "Academics". but in the 3rd row, although it belongs to c-level titles, the anchor-positive titles belongs to "Academics" but the negative goes into "Business Development" category.

How can i pass the categories into the training data for SBERT ?

I'm taking references from [here](https://www.sbert.net/docs/package_reference/losses.html)